# Why selected variables in dplyr package are not in output df in R?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, output

I have a df with 30 columns and 2000 rows.

from the df, I selected several variables by their name and calculated mean of Value by 3 by3 rows of group and type variables.

But there are only 3 variables (group, type, res) in output data.

How should I tell to save selected variables into output df? Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
output <- data %>%
  select(group, type, A, B, C, Value)  %>%
  group_by(group = gl(n()/3, 3), type) %>%
  summarise(res = mean(Value))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because `summarise` keep only the column summarised along with the grouping variables.  According to `?summarise` `Create one or more scalar variables summarizing the variables of an existing tbl. Tbls with groups created by group_by() will result in one row in the output for each group.`

Comment: If you need the all the columns, either group by all (if that makes sense) without the 'Value' and then summarise the 'Value' or use `mutate` instead of `summarise` and then get the `distinct` rows

Comment: @ akrun. I tried this way. but length of the output data frame even more increased than original df. observations of "group" variable are numbered from 1 to 10 in output. in original data they are coded like 25, 45, 200, 405 etc. Can I keep the original codes in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include them in `summarise` instead, e.g.:

```
output <- data %>%
  select(group, type, A, B, C, Value) %>%
  group_by(group = gl(n()/3, 3), type) %>%
  summarise(res = mean(Value), A=A[1], B=B[1], C=C[1] )
```

I believe this is the fastest approach under `dplyr` if you have a very large data.frame.

Comment: @ thc. It says "Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `type` is unknown"

Comment: group variable numbered from 1 to 10 in output. in original data its codes are 25, 45,  200, 405 etc. Can I keep the original codes in output? It would be the another alternative to solve my problem

Comment: Sorry, delete `type` since it was a grouping variable.  There are many different approaches, it is a common problem.  This approach is one way I like, but it may not fit exactly your needs.

Comment: @ thc. now it works fine. can I ask what the [1] is used for? what does this tell?

Comment: It just selects the first element in the group.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `summarize` only returns grouping variables and those  variables specified in `summarize`. This is by design – `summarize` returns a single row for each group, so there must be a single value for each variable.

The function used in `summarize` must return a single value (so that's covered), while using `group_by` with variables ensures that these variables are the same within the group. But for the other variables, there could be several different values within the group: which would `summarize` choose? Instead of making a guess, it drops those variables.

There are several options to get around this, which one is best  depends on your data and what you want to do with it:

1. Add these variables as grouping variables. This is the preferred method, but obviously it only works if the structure of the data allows it. For example, in a hypothetical dataset, if you want to group by `city` but want to preserve the `state` variable, using `group_by(city, state)` will divide into groups the same way as `group_by(city)` since city and state are linked (for example, "Boston" will always be with "MA").
2. Define them in `summarize` and choose only the first value to be the value for that group, as in [@thc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55910270/8366499). Note that you will lose any other values of those variables and it's not always clear which value will be kept and which will be lost.
3. Use `mutate` instead - this will keep the original number of rows rather than collapsing to 1 per group, but will ensure that you don't lose any data.
4. Join them as a comma (or other) separated string by adding: `A = paste(A, sep = ', ')` to the `summarize` for each variable you want to keep. This will preserve the information, at the expense of making it dificult to work with in any future steps.

Comment: Very helpful explanation. Thank you so much!